# x and y lengths differ in an apply

Tags: arrays, r, if-statement, apply

So I'm trying to run an apply function over an array. The idea is to look at the value in the risk factor column and if this is 1, use "OnsetFunction" and if it's a zero to use the HighOnsetFunction. The would then produce a column of values which populates another column in array.

```
> apply(OutComes, 1, function(x) { if(x["Risk_Factor"] == 1) 
> + {OnsetFunction()} 
> + else{ HighOnsetFunction()}})
```

I'm having trouble with the apply function above and keep getting this message.

```
>Error in xy.coords(x, y) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ
```

There are only five rows in the array at the moment as I'm trying to make sure the code works on a small group before I extend it to be many people, but I'm not sure what the x and y are. I've seen this message with graphs, but never with this before.

Comment: can you show your array ?

Comment: PersonNumber Risk_Factor OC_Death OnsetAge Clinical CS_Death Cure AC_Death
[1,]            1           1 99.69098       NA       NA       NA   NA       NA
[2,]            2           1 60.68009       NA       NA       NA   NA       NA
[3,]            3           0 88.67483       NA       NA       NA   NA       NA
[4,]            4           0 87.60846       NA       NA       NA   NA       NA
[5,]            5           0 78.23118       NA       NA       NA   NA       NA

Comment: Trying to change the fourth column based on the second's value of 1 or zero

Comment: OnsetFunction and HighOnsetFunction can you post them because without them can't simulate the task ... suspecting that those 2 functions won't process NAs and in this case you will have different size, one approach is to "code" that NAs or just fill up a vector with the answer because if you are use in the original dataframe than you'll need to: 1. remove NAs 2. code all NAs with 0: 2 1 60.68009 0 0 0 0 0 (this is based on your sample data)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to use `ifelse` but using `apply` and an `if`

Try:

```
ifelse(OutComes$Risk_Factor==1, OnsetFunction(), HighOnsetFunction())
```

Comment: Same problem still happening. Even with the ifelse on its own, ignoring the apply function.

    > ifelse(OutComes[,"Risk_Factor"] == 1, HighOnsetFunction(x), OnsetFunction(x))

This throws up the same x and y lengths differ problem.

Comment: @Ryan, Then the problem may reside in those functions. They may not be returning an array of the same length. For example: for some x one may be returning a single value and the other a two value array. Check both functions.